# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 when including header file

Tags: c, precompiled-headers

I am writing the following code to print the underlying Operative System. It's incomplete and might be wrong (appreciate advices for the *wrong*, no need for complete as it's for learning purposes).

**platform.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
                                                                                
void platform(int a)                                                            
{                                                                               
    #if __APPLE__                                                               
        printf("recognized apple\n");                                                                                           
    #elif __LINUX__                                                             
        printf("linux\n");                                                      
    #else                                                                       
        printf("unknown\n");                                                    
    #endif                                                                                                                                
                                                                                
    printf("%i\n",a);                                                           
}
```

If I add `main()` to *platform.c* and compile it, it works fine. However, as I am experimenting for learning purposes, including a header file:

**platform.h**

```
#ifndef PLATFORM_H_   /* Include guard */                                       
#define PLATFORM_H_                                                             
                                                                                
void platform(int);                                                             
                                                                                
#endif // PLATFORM_H_
```

and *lastly* including the header in a new file:

**Try.c**

```
#include "./platform.h"                                                         
                                                                                
                                                                                
int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    platform(4);                                                                
}
```

I compile it as:
`gcc try.c` and I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_platform", referenced from:
      _main in lala-10eeb5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please, go easy on me and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link platform.c to Try.c
Try using this command:

```
gcc try.c platform.c
```

You only included the declaration, not the implementation. This leads to a successful compiling, but linking will fail, as there is no implementation for `platform`.